# mysql create table- Error 1064 related to comments

Tags: mysql

Im newbie to Mysql and get an error while creating table, can you please let me know,

query

```
CREATE  TABLE schoolsy.Employees (

Emp_Num               INT(11)  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

Emp_First_Name    VARCHAR(30),

Emp_Last_Name    VARCHAR(30),

Emp_Middle_Name VARCHAR(30),

Emp_Gender            ENUM('M','F', 'N'),

Emp_Hire_Date      DATE,

Emp_End_Date      DATE,

Emp_Status             CHAR(1),

Row_Create_Ts    TIMESTAMP,

Row_Create_UserId  CHAR(30),

Row_Update_Ts    TIMESTAMP,

Row_Update_UserId CHAR(30) 

  PRIMARY KEY (Emp_Num)

COMMENT = 'This table contains all the employee details.';
```

New Error:

ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 'This table contains all the employee details.'' at line 15

SQL Statement:

```
CREATE  TABLE schoolsy.Employees (

Emp_Num               INT(11)  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

Emp_First_Name    VARCHAR(30),

Emp_Last_Name    VARCHAR(30),

Emp_Middle_Name VARCHAR(30),

Emp_Gender            ENUM('M','F', 'N'),

Emp_Hire_Date      DATE,

Emp_End_Date      DATE,

Emp_Status             CHAR(1),

Row_Create_Ts    TIMESTAMP,

Row_Create_UserId  CHAR(30),

Row_Update_Ts    TIMESTAMP,

Row_Update_UserId CHAR(30),

  PRIMARY KEY (Emp_Num),

COMMENT = 'This table contains all the employee details.'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing commas:

```
Row_Update_UserId CHAR(30),
                          ^--- here
  PRIMARY KEY (Emp_Num),
                       ^-- here
COMMENT = 'This table contains all the employee details.';
        ^--- remove
```

Comment: I have added but still get the same error..I have added the new error.

Comment: no `=` on the comment as well.

Comment: as well, general tip: you do NOT need to use `emp_` prefixes on your fields. that's pointless repetition of the table name. if you need to remindyourself of where a field comes from, you can ALWAYS use `tablename.fieldname` notation